# Is there any page/display that shows my "favorite" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, bookmarks

Sorry if I am missing something really obvious, but I have only recently discovered the "favorite question" feature, and would like to know where (if anywhere) all of the questions that I've personally tagged as "favorites" are displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, on your user page.  Click your name to go to it.  Then you'll see a "favorites" tab among the many.